# Python) I wanna add two lists which are different order of len

Tags: python, list, addition

I wanna add `list1=[1,2,3,4,5]` and `list2=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]`

What I desired is like

```
list3=[2,3,4,5,6,1,1]
```

This is my wrong code

```
lis1=[1,2,3,4,5] #len=5
list2=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1] #len=7
if len(list1)>len(list2):
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        list2.append(0) if list2[i]=[]
        list3[i]=list1[i]+list2[i]
else:
    for i in range(len(list2)):
        list1.append(o) if list1[i]=[]
        list3[i]=list1[i]+list2[i]
print(list3)
```

Comment: you want to add only the index which you **don't** have in list1 from list2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `izip_longest` from **itertools**

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import izip_longest
list1=[1,2,3,4,5]
list2=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
print([sum(i) for i in izip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue=0)])
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 1]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, when I try to run this after copy and paste,
I got this error
importError : cannot import name 'izip_longest'

Comment: `zip_longest` will also work, though it is slightly less efficient in this case.

Comment: python3 `from itertools import zip_longest`

Comment: ooohh !! after correcting to zip_longest, it works! by the way, what version is working well with izip_longest? I'm using python3, Do I have to upgrade this version so that I can use izip_longest?

Comment: @SatthewSeongHunMoon. Sorry i am using an old version(python2.7) :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to add the two list together, pad with 0 if a list is not long enough. so I modified directly from your code without any library:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5] #len=5
list2=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1] #len=7
list3 = [] # make a list3 
if len(list1)>len(list2):
    for i in range(len(list1)):
       # if list2[i]=[] this line is wrong, you can't compare non-exist element to a empty array
        if i >= len(list2):
            list2.append(0)
        list3.append(list1[i]+list2[i])
else:
    for i in range(len(list2)):
        if i >= len(list1):
            list1.append(0)
        list3.append(list1[i]+list2[i])
print(list3)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works well too! Actually I haven't learned library yet. So It's more useful!! Thanks! Can I ask you a personal thing?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to make this code as basic as possible. First of all, you **never** want to copy-paste your code. Your if/else statement should be evaluated first.

```
lis1=[1,2,3,4,5] #len=5
list2=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1] #len=7
longer, shorter = [], []
if len(list1) > len(list2):
    longer, shorter = list1, list2
else:
    longer, shorter = list2, list1
```

Now we have established which list is longer and which is shorter, by simply naming our lists `longer` and `shorter`. Our next task is programming alogrithm. What we want to do, is iterate `longer` list and add every int we find:

```
for i in range(len(longer)):
    longer[i] += shorter[i]
print(longer)
```

We try to run the program and **boom**, it fails with `out of range exception`. So we identify problem, and fix our code:

```
for i in range(len(longer)):
    if (i > len(shorter)): ## We make sure to not call shorter[i] if there is no such element
        longer[i] += shorter[i]
print(longer)
```

Any questions?

Comment: I started learning few days ago, So I have lots of things that I've not known. What does it mean of list1>list2? I just understood meaning of `list1 > list2` is list1 is longer than list2. But, when I runed print(list1>list2), I got 'true' eventhough list 2 is longer than list1. that's why I got confused what list1>list2 stands for.

Comment: @SatthewSeongHunMoon it's mistake, sorry. I didn't actually tried to run code I wrote. It's fixed now.